# Code Output Discrepency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I wrote some code last night to test some basic things. I used two sites to "live preview" my work, Dash and JSFiddle. On both sites, my code ran smoothly, but when I uploaded it live to the internet, none of my buttons functioned.

I tinkered with my code and was able to pinpoint the problem - for some reason on those websites I am able to append my div and then give it a function (such as mousedown/mouseup, etc.), yet on MY site I am not. I created both scenarios to explain:

1.) My original code that works in JSFiddle and Dash, but not on my site: ***http://jsfiddle.net/bEZ2z/4/***

```
<body>
  <div class="buttonHolder"></div>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       //append divs to class buttonHolder here
      });
      //code that makes div buttons function
  </script>
</body>
```

*(link to site of code above that doesn't work: alanpauley.com/color-fun)*

2.) My edited code that also works in JSFiddle and Dash, but more importantly, works on my site: ***http://jsfiddle.net/bEZ2z/3/***

```
<body>
  //create all divs here
   <script>
      //code that makes div buttons function
   </script>
</body>
```

*(link to site of code above that DOES work: alanpauley.com/color-fun2)*

So I already pinpointed the problem, but I'm more curious why this is. Is my script out of date/different? Is there something bigger going on that I'm unaware of when previewing on those sites that I also need to implement into my code?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, as I'd much rather use the code the initializes the divs in my jquery code rather than in the html itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the source of a **JSFiddle** page you will see that the jQuery scripts written within the "Javascript" area are wrapped in `$(window).load();` function:

So try wrapping your script within:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // code
});
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you, friend! :D